# Is there a way to dynamically change which attribute the toString method displays for custom classes?

Tags: java

I'm creating a JList in a Java GUI program that will be filled with the custom "SteamFriends" class via an ArrayList called friendsList:

```
friendsListJList.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
    SteamFriend[] friendListArr = friendsList.toArray(new SteamFriend [0]);
    public int getSize() { return friendListArr.length; }
    public SteamFriend getElementAt(int i) { return friendListArr[i]; }
});
```

Right now the toString() function returns the friendName of the SteamFriend object, but I'm wondering if it's possible to change it so that I can control what attribute it returns and what the best practice for it would be.

If I want to fill a JList with a list of SteamFriends which is sorted by age (for example), then how would I change the toString() method to display age? Through a static variable (public static int variableToDisplay) in the SteamFriend object, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better not to use `toString()` to display data to the user, but rather it is best used as a debugging tool. For JLists, I recommend that you instead use a custom cell renderer, one that you have written to display exactly what information you wish.

e.g. for one I've used in a program,

```
class LabelTextPairListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
   @Override
   public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value,
         int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
      LabelTextPairList labelTextPairList = (LabelTextPairList) value;
      if (labelTextPairList == null) {
         value = "";
      } else {
         value = labelTextPairList.getName();
      }
      return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected,
            cellHasFocus);
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this go in the initialization of the JList component somehow or does it go into the custom class and is automatically called when it's included in a JList?

Comment: @FedericoPettinella: per the [JList API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html), you call `setCellRenderer(...)` on the JList and pass in your renderer: `myList.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());`